# How `class` takes the value of `self` and working of `_init()_`

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, init, complex-numbers

I am learning about **classes** and **objects** in Python. I came across the following code:

```
class ComplexNumber:
    def __init__(self,r = 0,i = 0):
        self.real = r
        self.imag = i

    def getData(self):
        print("{0}+{1}j".format(self.real,self.imag))

# Create a new ComplexNumber object
c1 = ComplexNumber(2,3)

# Call getData() function
# Output: 2+3j
c1.getData()
```

I know that the first argument when `ComplexNumber` is called is `c1` itself which then is assigned to `self`. Then in `_init_`, `r` is assigned to `self.real`. How does it know that the type of `self` is complex number. If I am not wrong, `self.real` or `self.imag` can only be assigned to only variables of type `class 'complex'`.

But when I print the type of self it says: `<class '__main__.ComplexNumber'>`

Comment: It's not quite clear what your confusion is with regards to assigning `var.real` etc…

Comment: "If I am not wrong, var.real or var.imag can only be assigned to only variables of type class 'complex'." You are wrong.

Comment: @deceze I meant `var` as a general variable. To be specific here, `self.real` and `self.imag` can only be assigned to variables of type `class 'complex'` right? But how did it know that self is a complex number.

Comment: It didn't. You can freely assign anything to any object (with exceptions). Your `ComplexNumber` class logically becomes a "complex number" because it assigns itself `real` and `imag` in its `__init__`. It  doesn't have anything to do with the builtin `complex` type and Python doesn't "know" anything about your `ComplexNumber`.

Comment: `class Foo: pass; foo = Foo(); foo.bar = 'baz'` — No issues.

Comment: @deceze I totally get it now. So in `class ComplexNumber` a new object `self.real` is created. Yes, you are tight, I got confused with the builtin complex type.